# Annotation based springapplication with no web.xml not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-integration, spring-annotations

I am trying to build a spring project without the use of web.xml, but I am frequently getting this error, I've tried everything but so far nothing has solved the problem,

```
**Sep 15, 2015 11:36:50 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'**
```

here is my configuration:-

```
package com.springWeb.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcher    ServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n now deploying");
    return new String[]{ "/" };
}

}
```

My AppConfig Class

```
package com.springWeb.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springweb.controller.*")
@Import({ SpringSecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    System.out.println("\n\n\nello hello hello");
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver
            = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

}
```

And My controller

```
package com.springWeb.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class TestController {
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    System.out.println("test est test ets tstsd");
    return "index2";
}
}
```

Comment: Which version of Spring and tomcat are you utilizing? Might help.

Comment: How is your app deployed? As root (i.e. `/`) or as `/TestApp` if it is the first then the error is correct as there is no mapping for `/TestApp`.

Comment: I am using 4.2.1.RELEASE of spring, and using org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:run to deploy the application.

Comment: if I add a index.jsp in the webapp folder that page is accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's your `@ComponentScan` directive. Try changing it to

```
@ComponentScan({"com.springWeb.*"})
```

Looks like you maybe have a type-o with `com.springweb` in all lowercase.

Comment: Tried that @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springweb.controller.*") and @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springweb.controller") no combination is working

Comment: Have you tried with the proper case? Your package is `com.springWeb` not `com.springweb`?

Comment: It was a stupid mistake after thanks for noticing that, had been banging my head for nothing

Comment: Haha I know that feeling! I had a hell of a time figuring all of this out on my first run. Good luck!